# Numba performance issue with np.nan and np.inf

Tags: python, numpy, performance, numba

I am playing around with `numba` to accelerate my code. I notice that the performance varies significantly when using `np.inf` instead `np.nan` inside the function. Below I have attached three sample functions for illustration.

- `function1` is not accelerated by `numba`.
- `function2` and `function3` are both accelerated by `numba`, but one uses `np.nan` while the other uses `np.inf`.

On my machine, the average runtime of the three functions are `0.032284s`, `0.041548s` and `0.019712s` respectively. It appears that using `np.nan` is much slower than `np.inf`. Why does the performance vary significantly? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I am using `Python 3.7.11` and `Numba 0.55.Orc1`.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def function1(array1, array2):
    nr, nc = array1.shape
    output1 = np.empty((nr, nc), dtype='float')
    output2 = np.empty((nr, nc), dtype='float')
    output1[:] = np.nan
    output2[:] = np.nan

    for r in range(nr):
        row1 = array1[r]
        row2 = array2[r]
        diff = row1 - row2
        id_threshold =np.nonzero( (row1 - row2) > 8 )
        output1[r][id_threshold] = 1
        output2[r][id_threshold] = 0

    output1 = output1.flatten()
    output2 = output2.flatten()
    id_keep = np.nonzero(output1 != np.nan)
    output1 = output1[id_keep]
    output2 = output2[id_keep]
    output = np.vstack((output1, output2))
    return output

@nb.njit('float64[:,::1](float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1])', parallel=True)
def function2(array1, array2):
    nr, nc = array1.shape
    output1 = np.empty((nr,nc), dtype='float')
    output2 = np.empty((nr, nc), dtype='float')
    output1[:] = np.nan
    output2[:] = np.nan

    for r in nb.prange(nr):
        row1 = array1[r]
        row2 = array2[r]
        diff = row1 - row2
        id_threshold =np.nonzero( (row1 - row2) > 8 )
        output1[r][id_threshold] = 1
        output2[r][id_threshold] = 0

    output1 = output1.flatten()
    output2 = output2.flatten()
    id_keep = np.nonzero(output1 != np.nan)
    output1 = output1[id_keep]
    output2 = output2[id_keep]
    output = np.vstack((output1, output2))
    return output

@nb.njit('float64[:,::1](float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1])', parallel=True)
def function3(array1, array2):
    nr, nc = array1.shape
    output1 = np.empty((nr,nc), dtype='float')
    output2 = np.empty((nr, nc), dtype='float')
    output1[:] = np.inf
    output2[:] = np.inf

    for r in nb.prange(nr):
        row1 = array1[r]
        row2 = array2[r]
        diff = row1 - row2
        id_threshold =np.nonzero( (row1 - row2) > 8 )
        output1[r][id_threshold] = 1
        output2[r][id_threshold] = 0
    output1 = output1.flatten()
    output2 = output2.flatten()
    id_keep = np.nonzero(output1 != np.inf)
    output1 = output1[id_keep]
    output2 = output2[id_keep]
    output = np.vstack((output1, output2))
    return output


array1 = 10*np.random.random((1000,1000))
array2 = 10*np.random.random((1000,1000))

output1 = function1(array1, array2)
output2 = function2(array1, array2)
output3 = function3(array1, array2)
```

Comment: Which version of numba are you using? I get an error on `0.51.2`.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Please see the edited post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one is much slower because `output1 != np.nan` returns a copy `output1` since `np.nan != np.nan` is `True` (like any other value -- `v != np.nan` is always true). Thus, the resulting array to compute are much bigger causing a slower execution.

The point is you must **never compare a value to `np.nan` using comparison operators: use `np.isnan(value)`** instead. In your case, you should use `np.logical_not(np.isnan(output1))`.

The second implementation may be slightly slower due to the temporary array created by `np.logical_not` (I did not see any statistically significant difference on my machine between using NaN or Inf once the code has been corrected).